# Center a bootstrap registration form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a registration page in the center of my html page. I am using bootstrap, but a little confused how to center it after a couple of attempts.
Here is part of the html page I am working on. These html code goes to the `<body>`:

```
<div class="container registration-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="registerHere" method='post' action=''>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Registration</legend>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="user_email" name="user_email" rel="popover" data-content="What’s your email address?" data-original-title="Email">
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Create My Account</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group success">
                        <!-- TODO -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group error">
                        <!-- TODO -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS I am trying to make this registration form looks good:

```
.registration-container{
position: relative;
background: rgba(240, 248, 255, 0.5);
width: 600px;
/*margin-top: 40%;*/
margin-bottom: auto;
}

legend{
text-align: center;
}
```

However, this form looks really ugly: the legend is not centered and not fit in the container, and everything looks strange.... Can someone please help me figure out how I can make this form be more professional and good styled?

Comment: Provide a demo. Seems fine here: http://jsbin.com/OZImEHu/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This css this will work fine **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/tUeez/)**

```
.registration-container{
position: relative;
background: rgba(240, 248, 255, 0.5);
width: 600px;
 margin:0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this with using property in css - margin: 0 auto;

```
.registration-container{
position: relative;
background: rgba(240, 248, 255, 0.5);
width: 600px;
/*margin-top: 40%;*/
margin-bottom: auto;
margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.registration-container{ margin: 0 auto; }
```

set your container Center of the screen :)